# Approximate function observed through noise

Tags: mean, approximation

I have a function $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that I can observe through some noise, i.e. I can only directly measure $f(x) + \eta$ where $\eta$ is some random noise with mean 0.

I have a large number of noisy observations of this function, $f_i$, at *different* arguments $x_i$.  What is a good way to approximate the function for any $x \in [a,b]$?

If I had several observations of $f(x_0)$ at the *same* $x_0$ then I could average over these to estimate the true $f(x_0)$.  But while I have a relatively large number of observations, each one is at a different argument $x_i$.   What is the best course of action in this case?

---

I have no background in statistics so excuse me if this is a basic question.  What I'd like t know is if there's some sane theory to handle these situation (which would be much better than myself coming up with some ad-hoc solution such as moving averages).  The names of some methods I could use would be sufficient, I can look up the details.  Note: I would like to use the approximated $f$ mainly for things such as optimization and finding zero crossings.

---

My data is similar to this artificially generated dataset (Mathematica code):

```
n = 500;
data = {#, Sin[#] + RandomReal[.1 {-1, 1}]} & /@ RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, n];

ListPlot[data]
```

[image]

Comment: Is the form of $f$ known (up to some parameter-values, which are to be estimated from the data), or unknown? If unknown, are you prepared to restrict yourself to say 'smooth functions' (in some sense), or say continuous functions -- or might it contain jumps? Is your function periodic, as in the example? Is the form of the error term uniform as in the example? Something you can say some things about? Or unknown? The known case would in general be *nonlinear regression*, the unknown case would be *nonparametric regression* or *smoothing*.

Comment: @Glen_b It's not known (otherwise it would be a standard fitting exercise). For now we can assume the function to be "nice": no discontinuities in the function. (Well, my actual data has a near-discontinuous *derivative*.)  Yes, my data looks pretty similar to the example, at least regarding the number of data points and the magnitude of the error compared to the magnitude of the variation in the function. [This is one of my *actual* datasets](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38623/data.csv), but I'm sure I'll need to do this again the future so I asked for a general solution.

Comment: @Glen_b I looked up nonparametric regression on Wikipedia, and I think that's enough to get me started.  Sometimes all you need is the keyword ...  I can research the rest.

Comment: One thing to note with your data is that it doesn't have constant variance. Because your second variable looks restricted to (0,1) you may also find it easier to fit with some transformed version of your data (in that the curvature changes strongly, making some forms of nonparametric fit harder). But it looks like with some appropriate choices, you should get quite satisfactory results.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want to use the fitted $f(x)$ to find max / min or zero crossings I would not use a nonparametric approach.  Instead in order to find a max, for example, use only the data near the max value of your actual data and fit a quadratic polynomial using least squares.  Then you can easily use the first order condition to obtain a max.

To find a zero crossing I would just use the data in a neighborhood of your closest data point to zero to fit a linear function of $x$, again by least squares.